# Socket Exception in Visual Studio load test

Tags: sockets, visual-studio-2012, load-testing

While executing a load test within Visual Studio I keep hitting the following error:

> SocketException   Only one usage of each socket address
>   (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted x.x.x.x:443

once I ramp up to a certain number of users. Now I have adjusted the registry settings regarding the MaxUserPort (to 65534) and the TcpTimedWaitDelay (to 30) and this has made no difference.

This is Visual Studio 2012 on Windows Server 2012.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, since you haven't provided enough information, you are binding and connecting outbound sockets, and you are trying to re-use local port numbers. You can't do that. Get rid of the bind step and let the system allocate the local port number. However you will then discover that you still run out of ports with a bind error, or possibly this *is* the bind error, and this is because using a single client program as a server load test is fundamentally invalid. Your only recourse is to use fewer connections and more client hosts as well.